# How to send a dm to another person discord.js? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot and I wrote this code, but it gives an error, `user.dm is not a function`.

My code:

```
if(message.content.startsWith('s!modöner')) {
    let mesajöner = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    let userdm = 767387717792563241
    userdm.send(mesajöner);
    message.reply('Quixe Öneriniz Gönderildi.');
}
```

Comment: i might be misunderstanding your code, but is the purpose of it to run s!dm [user] and it will dm that user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the `userdm` variable is a user id, and you want to DM that user. In that case, you would first have to get the user from [`client.users.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=cache), then you can send it. An example:

```js
const user = client.users.cache.get('767387717792563241')
user.send(mesajöner)
```

(Note: In discord, all ids are [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)s, so any id you use should be used as a string instead of a number like you have)